# php mysql - add user_id to session variable

Tags: php, mysql

When I register a user I add them to a database and they get an id which is auto generated by auto_increment. Now I'm trying to add that id to a session variable so I can use it on other pages in the website and manipulate their row in the database. This is what I have so far.

This line adds the form inputs to the db when the user registers:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('example','values'))");
```

Then I'm trying to get the user_id into a variable that I can use on other pages of the website. I'm trying this:

```
if ($insert) {
  $select_id = mysql_query("SELECT `id` from `users` WHERE `email` = '$form_input'");
  $id_arr = mysql_fetch_array($select_id);
  $id_var = $id_arr['id'];
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["Register"] = $id_var[0];
}
```

But it doesn't work so I'm trying a var_export to see what's in $id_var and I get a value of '3' which doesn't match the user_id that supposed to be stored in the variable.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statements

Comment: I think $id_var[0] points nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the result set to get the value of `id`

```
$id="";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_id))   
{    
  $id= $row ['id'];
}
if($id!=""){
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["Register"] = $id;
}
```

Note: mysql_query was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.Alternatives to this function include: `mysqli_query() or PDO::query()`

Moreover, passing the values directly into the query is not safe. Please, read about `SQL injection`

Comment: You should not suggest solution for the deprecated `mysql_*` API

Comment: the code is vulnerable to SQL injection too but that doesn't mean I would write the implementation. I can tell him the logic to fix his existing code and yes can add up some suggestions though. Shouldn't be a down vote as far I think. @Jens

Comment: At least you can add a comment, that user shoild not use this API

Comment: Thanks @DanyalSandeelo. I'll look into the improved versions later. Right now I can't even wrap my head around the old versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_insert_id()`

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (1, 2, 3, 'blah')");
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

See this : [mysql_insert_id()](http://au.php.net/mysql_insert_id)

**Note:** mysql_query was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.Alternatives to this function include: [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: what if someone else inserts another row right there?

Comment: You should not suggest solution for the deprecated `mysql_*` API

Answer (score 0):

as Comments by `Jens`. I strongly recommend to use `mysqli` or even better `PDO`. As `mysql` is `depreciated` and completely removed in `PHP7`.

now as per your code try this

```
 if ($insert) {
      $select_id = mysql_query("SELECT `id` from `users` WHERE `email` = '$form_input'") or die(mysql_error());// to see error
if($select_id != null){
      $id_arr = mysql_fetch_array($select_id);
      $id_var = $id_arr['id'];
      session_start();
      $_SESSION["Register"] =   $id_var;
    }
}
```